# XML instead of HTML inside Jinja

Tags: flask, jinja2

I found myself using this kind of code in an app that uses Flask, Python, and Jinja:

```
<div class="member">Mircea Lungu</div>
<div class="member">Riri Lungu</div>
```

when what I would really love to do is this:

```
<member>Mircea Lungu</member>
<member>Riri Lungu</member>
```

and specify somewhere else the fact that a `<member>` has to be mapped on an a certain kind of `<div>`. It would allow a nicer separation of content and formatting.

What's the best way of achieving this?

Comment: I do not see how your code examples are related to Jinja. Could you try to be more specific e.g. provide the Jinja code which generates this?

Comment: Jinja2 is a templating language. It's intended for HTML, but it can be used for anything, really. There's absolutely nothing stopping you from generating the output you describe.

Comment: Hmm. I guess my question would be more: what would be the idiomatic way of avoiding to repeat the formatting stuff (with div and class) and focusing on describing the data instead. Now that I think about it, probably I should be using some kind of macro instead.

Answer (score 9):

Depends on how you want to display it, but you can do something like this:

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/sitemap.xml')
def sitemap():

    values = [
        {'name': 'John', 'surname': 'Doe', 'age': 25},
        {'name': 'Jane', 'surname': 'Doe', 'age': 19}
    ]

    template = render_template('sitemap.xml', values=values)
    response = make_response(template)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/xml'

    return response
```

**sitemap.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    {% for val in values %}
    <person>
        <name>{{val.name}}</name>
        <surname>{{val.surname}}</surname>
        <age>{{val.age}}</age>
    </person>
    {% endfor %}
</urlset>
```

You can also check out this **[snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/108/)** posted on the flask site.